# DataTable.Select retrieving all rows?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have this code:

```
allGyms.Select("type = 1");
foreach(DataRow allGymsRow in allGyms.Rows)
{

}
```

The allGyms stored 25 rows, 7 rows with a type of 1 and another 7 with a type of 2 and so on.. Now I'm trying to use the current `DataTable` to retrieve the rows with a type of 1, so it should return 7 rows.. However when I debug into the foreach loop, the allGyms has 25 rows rather than the expected 7..

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: select is for projection not for filtering, use where

Comment: Haven't done this in a long time, but you might want to use a `DataView` to restrict the rows returned from the `DataTable`.

Comment: Using the Where doesn't work.. It doesn't take a string as a parameter ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers are talking about the [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method on IEnumerable.

I believe you are trying to use the Select method on [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If that is the case the problem is you are not saving the filtered array that the method is returning. You need to save the returned array and then foreach through that.

```
var filteredRows = allGyms.Select("type = 1");
foreach(DataRow allGymsRow in filteredRows)
{ 
    ...
}
```

Comment: or call it on the foreach 

`foreach(DataRow allGymRow in allGymes.Select("type = 1").Rows)`

Also Mumbo, you'll need a `.Rows` in there somewhere.

Comment: You shouldn't need a .Rows.  The Select returns a DataRow[] already that you can directly iterate over.

Comment: Thank you, you're  the only person who seemed to have understood what I wanted and had a simple approach, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Select() applies a method to every element. It is an elegant way to mutate the elements in a collection such as an array.

I think you want to create a DataTable so that you may run database queries from your aspx.cs file like so:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(Application["ConnectionString"].ToString()))
        {
            con.Open();
            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE type = 1";
            OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(strSQL, con);
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                return dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
        }
        return "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Select and Where together:

```
allGyms.Select().Where(t => t.type == 1);
```

Comment: I think you need an `AsEnumerable()` in there - i.e., `allgyms.AsEnumerable().Select().Where(t => t.type == 1);`.